# Ionic IOS plugin with multiple files - Import Error

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am writing a custom IOS plugin in Ionic application specific for IOS. I created a plugin using Plugman and it worked.

I aslo have existing objective C code from the previous version of the project which needs to be re-used. When I try importing a `.h` file in the `.m` file which is been created when using Plugman, it throws the below error.

```
fatal error: 'XYCManager.h' file not found
#import "XYCManager.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **
```

I am Android based and lack knowledge in Objective C standard / syntax. Couldn't find appropriate blogs too. Can't I manage or work with more files(.h & .m) when using Ionic Cordova plugins ?

Comment: you should post more information, in example the plugin.xml content as that's where the native classes are mapped

Comment: Eventhough I posted minimal information, you provided your comments which helped me. The problem is I didn't add the source and header files reference in plugin.xml. Thanks a lot for the solution given.